# Which technology should one use while designing a web app - HTML5 + CSS3 or HTML4 + CSS2?

Tags: html, css

If I want to work on a web app with 2-3 months of timeframe in mind, which technology should I use? HTML5 + CSS3 or HTML4 + CSS2?

Few points I am considering

- Compatibility of browsers
- Ease of use (especially with IE)
- Advantages over html4
- Learning curve

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? What about IE6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases, I'd avoid any of the new elements introduced in HTML 5. They tend to need JavaScript in order to render correctly in some commonly used browsers, and don't provide much in the way of practical benefits today.

Some of the APIs can be useful, but need to be taken on a case by case basis … and still function in HTML 4.01 documents.

Avoid CSS 2 in favour of CSS 2.1 (since it better reflects what browsers actually do). Examine CSS 3 properties and selectors on a case by case basis, comparing benefits, browser support, and what happens in the cases that browsers don't support them.

Comment: Amen to case-by-case, as per the first item on this page http://diveintohtml5.org/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Don't get hung up about standards. Pick what ever features you need from what works in browsers. Design with Progressive Enhancement and Graceful Degradation in mind.

Comment: Ignoring standards and picking from current browser implementations is how we still have sites that require IE 6.

Comment: @Chuck Sites that *require* IE 6? Haven't seen that since 2002 :)

Comment: @Chuck - Not getting hung up about standards, is not the same thing as ignoring them. The HTML5 draft is hugely useful in understanding where HTML is heading, and thus can be useful in ones progressive enhancement choices. But to build a web site for the general public this year attempting to exploit many HTML5 features is an exercise in futility.